# How-to / Can You Generate Sequence or Data Flow Diagrams from Imported Database in Enterprise Architect 15?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'd like to generate sequence diagrams or data flow diagrams (or both) automatically for stored procedures from an imported database model in Enterprise Architect 15. Is this possible? How do you do it?

Comment: Generating SDs from code is not only impossible but just absolutely worthless. What would you think you could achieve with endless SDs. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: There a research tool for understanding legacy code

Comment: Pls. read the wiki article and try to understand it.

Comment: I cannot see how relevant the `Halting_problem` is here. I know about `Halting_problem`. Understanding legacy code is NOT a `Halting_problem`. I have created a tool to generate sequence diagrams from code (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12437-zenuml-support?). It is not perfect, but it does make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

EA can import stored procedures, but it doesn't parse the code and doesn't make any behavioral diagrams from the content.